# Need more fields than 'className' '_objCount' and 'id' when making a find() query against Parse.com

Tags: parse-platform

When making a find() request against Parse.com, each of the results I get back only contain the following fields: 'className' '_objCount' and 'id'.

How to get all fields ? (I have more than 3 columns in the database browser)
How to get specific fields ?

UPDATE 1

1) [Screenshot of the headers of my class, named "Code"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bvVnz.png)

2) Query:

```
var Code = Parse.Object.extend('Code');
var query = new Parse.Query(Code);
query.equalTo('codeSet', codeSet);
query.find()
.then(function(codes) {
  console.log(codes);
}
```

3) Results:

```
[ { className: 'Code', _objCount: 1, id: '6cMkEQxE6A' },
{ className: 'Code', _objCount: 2, id: 'uOU7osLvOo' },
{ className: 'Code', _objCount: 3, id: 'Vks4QEpBlh' },
{ className: 'Code', _objCount: 4, id: 'dWtukZhsHZ' } ]
```

UPDATE 2

The code is hosted in a heroku-hosted node.js instance

Comment: The default is all of them.  The only way not to get all of them that I know of is to include a subset in a select qualifier on the query.  To get better help, post the code and a snapshot of the header row in the databrower

Comment: @danh I've updated the post with code and snaphsot or the header row in the databrowser

Comment: The header row indicates string fields "key" and "alias", but the code shown tries to qualify on "codeSet".  The results shown have different fields altogether and do not resemble results from any parse query of any class.

Comment: @adolfosrs It's js cloud code, hosted in a node.js instance at heroku

Comment: @danh I updated the screenshot so the last column appears - "codeSet".

Comment: Still, the results are nonsensical.  Not even parse objects.  Lets see the result of the console log in the then block.

Comment: @danh the array I've already copied in my question is actually what I get from console.log(codes))

Comment: I'm also seeing this with a relatively straightforward query. Can you post any updates you on this thread.... https://github.com/ParsePlatform/Parse-SDK-JS/issues/258#issuecomment-243287965

Comment: You're seeing an abbreviated version of your objects. Use `codes.forEach(code => console.log(code.toJSON()))` to get the complete object.

Comment: @MadsFoliBjerre you're right. Facing the same issue this solved it. Thxs

Answer (score 1):

Use PFObject get method. like user.get('nickname');

https://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Object.html

Comment: Link is outdated (since parse docs moved to Github) but this still solved my problem. Current link to docs is [https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#methods_get](https://parseplatform.github.io/Parse-SDK-JS/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#methods_get); In OP case, he should do `codes[i].get('alias');` instead of `codes[i].alias;`, for instance.

Answer (score 1):

Just incase anyone comes accross this problem, I'm going to post an answer as it took me several hours to find the solution, which is to use `toJSON()`.

Example:

```
  var Parse = require('parse/node');
  var User = Parse.Object.extend("User");
  const query = new Parse.Query(User);

  await query.get("object-id-here")
  .then((user) => {
    // The object was retrieved successfully.
    console.log("The User Object", user.toJSON())

  }, (error) => {
    // The object was not retrieved successfully.
    console.log("Error:", error)

  });
```